# Firestore - good practice to use uid of FirebaseAuth as the document index for further relations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i have a simple question regarding if it's a good practice to use the `uid` of the FirebaseAuth-Service for relations in other collections as the document index. So on login I get the uid of the FirebaseUser. With that I create an user like so:

[image: create user]

Now is that a good practice to use this uid as the index of another document somewhere in another collection like this:

[image: sub_collection]

Or is it more common to let the index be generated and add an `uid` field inside the document so that I can query it with `'uid' equal 'my_uid'` for example?

I come from the SQL-side and I don't have that much experience about NoSQL and how to sturcture it well. It would be great if someone could give me an advice here.

Comment: i use this approach in all my projects and it works fine

Comment: Same here, it makes rules easier to write

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem at all to reuse the same document ID in different collections, whether this id is a user uid (from Auth) or any other value (including an auto generated Firestore id).

---

> Or is it more common to let the index be generated and add an uid
>   field inside the document so that I can query it with 'uid' equal
>   'my_uid' for example?

This is also a common approach, which can be interesting for example if you don't want to display the value of a Firestore document id (for example in an an url like https://www.whatever.com/players/-useruid- or https://www.whatever.com/players/-playername-).

Note however that this can generate some "tricky" side effects: for example if you want to avoid having two user profiles with the same `user_name`, in order to check that into a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions), you need to use the `user_name` as the id of the documents, since, with the Client SDKs it is not possible to execute a query within a Transaction (you need to define a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to pass to the Transaction's [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction#get) method).